# Access Child component html element from the parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

*attendees.component.html* (Parent)

```
 <app-add-guest (guestUserChange)="addGuest($event)"></app-add-guest>
```

*add-guest.component.html* (Child)

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="stacked" color="light">Guest name</ion-label
        >

        <ion-input // this input here
          formControlName="guestName"
          color="light"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Guest name"
       >
        </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</form>
```

Can you tell me how to access `ion-input` from the parent component? Because I need to setfocus on that input within the parent component.

I saw a lot of examples of how to access the child component method using `@ViewChild`. But not for my use case above.

Comment: @DM Great. I have thought about the other way around. Please put that as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're following proper separation of concerns, the parent shouldn't know anything about the template of the child. Add a method to the child that [focuses the input](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#setfocus) and have the parent call this method when appropriate.

```js
@Component({
    /* ... */
    selector: 'app-add-guest',
    template: `
        <!-- ... -->
        <ion-input // this input here
          formControlName="guestName"
          color="light"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Guest name"
        >
        <!-- ... -->
    `,
})
export class AddGuestComponent {
  @ViewChild(IonInput) guestNameInput?: IonInput;

  focusInput(): void {
    this.guestNameInput?.setFocus();
  }
}

@Component({
    /* ... */
    template: `<app-add-guest></app-add-guest>`,
})
export class AttendeesComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(AddGuestComponent) child?: AddGuestComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.child?.focusInput();
  }
}
```